# FullScreen modalView can't rotate on iPad iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

Code:

```
HDComposeViewController *vc = [[HDComposeViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

The present modal view can't rotate while device rotated. If I change `modalPresentationStyle` to `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`, it works!!!

HDComposeViewController has already implement rotate delegate:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

Is there anything wrong? Thanks.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628685/ipad-modal-view-not-rotating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a category for navigation controlller to rotate in ios 6.

```
@interface UINavigationController (RotationAll)
    -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
@end

@implementation UINavigationController (RotationAll)
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```